# Restrict results for Google Places autocomplete to allow only addresses with building

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I use [Google Places Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) to present list of predictions to the user while it's typing.
My requirement is to allow users to pick only addresses that include building number (street_number in API terms).

The configuration I use is shown below:

```
let gac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                  (autocomplete), {
                    types: ['address'],
                    componentRestrictions: {'country': ["us"]},
                    fields: ['formatted_address', 'address_components']
                  }
                );
```

With this settings user can pick address that includes only Street name without building part specified.

I can add validation message if user picks address without building number (street_number of an address_componenst arrey, but I would not like to show such results at all.

I studied the [list of Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#Types) that I can use to restrict results, but didn't find any better than "address".
upd. With "establishments" type I miss some addresses.

Can someone suggest an approach to meet my requirements?

Comment: You could try to use `types: ['establishments']` that instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only business results. For your reference, please check the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3

Comment: @jabamataro, with this type I can't find some addresses. Edited the original post.

Comment: Having the same issue.. Has anyone found a viable solution?

Comment: @product_nick, there are no standard way to exclude such addresses from results. I've solved this by adding custom validation that says something like "choose location with more specific address"